# Combine n recordset items into groups of 3

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to get n number of items from a recordset and I want to loop through the recordset placing them into divs with 3 items in each div. I would imagine one would do so using iteration and a counter to open and close each div in doing so. I would be really curious to know what would be the most efficient means to do so.

I would imagine one would start with a div, then begin iteration, incrementing the counter (initial value of 1) by 1 with each loop. If counter mod 3 = 0 then close the div and reopen. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: Right track? I'm not even convinced you're using the right mode of transport

Comment: Yes, Manav, that is a question. I forgot the ? symbol. Thanks Tom, I thought I was on the right path I just thought there might be a more efficient method than what I was thinking.